# Cellular Automata returns all 0s [PYTHON]

Tags: python, random, noise, perlin-noise, cellular-automata

I have written a program (see below) as an implementation of cellular automata in python. When I run the program, I receive a pattern of random seeded noise and the new pattern that has been run through the program. The "." are zeros and the "#" is a one. The issue is, when I run the program I receive the random noise (looks right) but when I receive the smoothed version, I only get periods (zeros).

**app.py**

```
import perlin

line = ""

noise = perlin.Noise(20,20, 420, 1)

print(" ")

for i in range(20):
    line += "="
print(line)

# Parses smoothed map
line = ""

print(" ")
for i in range(len(noise.map)):
    for j in range(len(noise.map[i])):
        if noise.map[i][j] == 0:
            line += "."
        else:
            line += "#"
    print(line)
    line = ""
```

**perlin.py**

```
import numpy as np

class Noise:
    def inbounds(self,x,y):
        if (x >= 0 and x <= self.width) and (y >=0 and y <= self.height):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def smooth(self,iterations):
        for i in range(iterations):
            temp_map = self.map
            for j in range(self.height):
                for k in range(self.width):
                    neighbor_wall_count = 0
                    for y in range(j-1,j+1):
                        for x in range(k-1, k+1):
                            if self.inbounds(x,y):
                                if y != j or x != k:
                                    if temp_map[y][x] == 1:
                                        neighbor_wall_count += 1
                            else:
                                neighbor_wall_count += 1
                    if neighbor_wall_count > 3:
                        self.map[j][k] = 1
                    else:
                        self.map[j][k] = 0


    def __init__(self, width, height, seed, iter):
        # Sets all of the self variables
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.seed = seed
        np.random.seed(self.seed)
        w, h = self.width, self.height
        # Declares the pattern map list
        map = [[0 for i in range(w)] for j in range(h)]

        #Generator
        for y in range(h):
            for x in range(w):
                map[y][x] = np.random.randint(0,2)
        self.map = map

        # Parser
        line = ""
        for i in range(len(self.map)):
            for j in range(len(self.map[i])):
                if self.map[i][j] == 0:
                    line += "."
                else:
                    line += "#"
            print(line)
            line = ""
        self.smooth(iter)
```

**Output**

```
#..###.#....#...#..#
..#####..##.#.###..#
###.###.###..####...
###....##..###.#.#..
#.#.###..##...##..##
#......#..#..#.##..#
.###.#.#.##..#...##.
##...##....#####..#.
#..##...#....###..#.
#.....#.##.####...##
#..#..#.#.##..##..#.
.#.###.###...#..#..#
...#.##....#..#.##..
#.#..#.#.#.###..####
.#..#....#..##.###..
#..#.#.#........###.
.#####..#.#..####...
##..#.#.##.##..#..##
##.#.#.##.####.#..##
####.........##..##.
 
====================
 
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
```

Comment: oh my... it was so simple and yet i spent so much time. python ranges have end excluded. `for y in range(j-1,j+2)` (same for `x`). you'll have to correct `inbounds` too (`x < self.width` same for `y`)

Comment: I made the changes but instead of all zeros, I get all ones.

Comment: you have to tune the `neighbor_wall_count`

Comment: Oh my God. Absolute legend. It was so small I could not see it. Life saver, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the stop argument in [python ranges](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) is excluded from the range (range < stop)

> For a positive step, the contents of a range r are determined by the
> formula r[i] = start + step*i where i >= 0 and r[i] < stop.
>
> For a negative step, the contents of the range are still determined by
> the formula r[i] = start + step*i, but the constraints are i >= 0 and
> r[i] > stop.

you can tune the smoothness (eg 3 here), by changing the value of that test:

`if neighbor_wall_count > 3:`